# rails NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create after adding checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I received the following error after adding checkbox in article view (_form)

> NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create
>   undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #52): 50 51 52 53 54 55

```
@article = Article.new(article_params)
@article.user = current_user
if @article.save
   flash[:success]="Your Tip has been Created"
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
else
```

this is the view page  _form in article view:

```
<%=render'shared/errors',obj: @article%>

   <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-xs-12'>
     <%= form_for(@article, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
   <div class='form-group'>
   <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
    <%= f.label :title %>
   </div>
   <div class ="col-sm-7">
    <%= f.text_field :title,class:"form-control",placeholder:"Title of Tip",autofocus:true %>
   </div>
   </div>
         <div class='form-group'>
           <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
    <%= f.label :description %>
           </div>
           <div class ="col-sm-8">
    <%= f.text_area :description,rows:10,class:"form-control",placeholder:"Make it short" %>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
               <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
                   <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
               <% end %>
           </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class='form-group'>
           <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit class:'btn btn-danger btn-lg'%>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
    [<%= link_to 'Cancel and Back to Tips',articles_path%>]
         </div>
<% end %>
   </div>
   </div>
```

this is the article controller :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_article,only: [:edit ,:update ,:destroy,:show]
   before_action :require_user,except: [:index,:show]
   before_action :require_same_user,only:[:edit,:update,:destroy]

   def home
   redirect_to articles_path
   end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 6 )

  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new

  end

  def destroy

    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path
    flash[:danger] = "ِYour Tip has been Deleted"

  end

  def edit


  end

  def update

    if @article.update(article_params)
       flash[:success] = "ِYour Tip has been Updated"
       redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

  end

  def show


  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.user = current_user
    if @article.save
       flash[:success]="Your Tip has been Created"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_article
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

   def article_params
     params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description, category_ids:[])

   end

  def require_same_user
 if current_user !=  @article.user and !current_user.admin?
   flash[:danger]="You can only Edit your own Tips"
   redirect_to articles_path
 end
  end
end
```

I have added check box to let user select category to his article, but received the mention error.

this is the Repository Link :
   https://github.com/essam11/Tips-Gator`

```
enter code here
```

UPDATE:
this is the error that i see in cmd

```
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2017-01-25 14:26:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-01-25 14:26:27] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x64-mingw32]
[2017-01-25 14:26:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3884 port=3000


Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-25 14:26:28 -0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PhHhY2JjMjNVM+bT8UmXTRcduOdq9DRKJxKzJz3OfIQ=", "article"=>{"title"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "description"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "category_ids"=>["1", ""]}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  User Load (7.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:75: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:79: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:83: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:102: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
  Category Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Category Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."name" = 'Windows' AND "categories"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (42.0ms)  INSERT INTO "articles" ("created_at", "description", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 25 Jan 2017 22:26:29 UTC +00:00], ["description", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"], ["title", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"], ["updated_at", Wed, 25 Jan 2017 22:26:29 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 9]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "article_categories" ("article_id", "category_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["article_id", 66], ["category_id", 1]]
   (57.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 470ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:52:in `create'


  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (13.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (1231.8ms)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error message including the stack trace?

Comment: i added the error that i see in cmd , could you check it Please?

Comment: Look at the params: `"category_ids"=>["1", ""]` It seems like you send an invalid category id to the application.

Comment: so what? what can i do ?

Comment: any suggestion ??